# With React-Native, how can I use flex to have 2 expanding Views?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have 3 `<View>`'s that are stacked vertically... the first has a fixed height. The third should expand based on its content up to a limit.

The middle one should expand to fill the space in between the 2.

Something like:

```
<View styles={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
   <View styles={{height: 50}}>... stuff here... </View>
   <View styles={{flexGrow: 1}}>... stuff here... </View>
   <View styles={{maxHeight: '50%'}}>... stuff here... </View>

</View>
```

But that doesn't really work out. I feel like this is simple, but I can't quite get it right. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on track, but I guess the main mistake comes from using "styles" instead of "style" prop.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <View style={{height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        <Text>... stuff here...</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
        <Text>... stuff here...</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{maxHeight: '50%', backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
        <Text>... stuff here...</Text>
        <Text>... stuff here...</Text>
        <Text>... stuff here...</Text>
        <Text>... stuff here...</Text>
        <Text>... stuff here...</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can see how it works [here](https://snack.expo.dev/A8Oe1UCdr)